# How to integrate Python3 with Native Script app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nativescript, nativescript-angular

How to integrate Python3 functions with Native Script app ? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: probably like in normal JavaScript you would have to send requests to server which can run Python (directly in framework like Flask, Django or using CGI extension) and it would send result from Python script.  Eventually you could try to convert Python to JavaScript ie. using [Transcrypt](https://www.transcrypt.org/examples) but it has no access to modules which are only on server. Similar [RapydScript](https://github.com/atsepkov/RapydScript)

Comment: This server with flask would have to be on the outside, on the network?

Comment: yes, it has to be external server with Flask or with CGI (or even with PHP server which can use `exect()` to run Python script). I don't know if you could embed it in code with app. Besides it would need `Python` interpreter for your device (if it only exist for your device) and different CPU may need different interpreter. I don't know if you could use [Jyton](https://www.jython.org/) which runs on Java.

Comment: you can download from server, not from app. Someone would have to replace server to get data send from application. Or it would have to work as man-in-the-middle to listen all connections in network. But someone can send own parameters to server to get results. To send data you could use password which is hidden in app and server. To get password from server you would have to hack server - it can be hard or impossible job. To get password from app you would have to decompile code - and it can be easier job.

Comment: In my application I'm sending an image to python code, which has to do some operations on it, so I think it can be done by uploading the image to the server, where PHP script will perform python operation, and then the application will retrieve the result from the server. I still need to develop some kind of connectivity to make it safe and I think it could work.